# SendGrid: "batch id not found"

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm playing around with the v3 API and trying to demo the concept of scheduling emails and then cancelling them. Here is what I did:

- Created a batch with `POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/batch` and got batch a batch ID
- Did a mail send with `POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send` and included that batch ID as the `batch_id` parameter and put in a future `send_at` time
- Attempted to pass that batch ID into `POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/user/scheduled_sends/:batch_id`

However the latter call fails as 404 Not Found with `"message": "batch id not found"`. In fact it would seem that however many batch IDs I create, attempting to update them always yields this not-found message. The result is, the scheduled send cannot be cancelled, and the email sends at the appointed time. I should add that attempting to `GET /v3/mail/batch/{batch_id}` returns an empty array `[]`.

Am I doing something wrong here?? Is this a limitation of the free account perhaps?

**EDIT**: I'm going to add some raw details to show what I am doing. I am doing these in Postman but I will export in cURL syntax to demonstrate.

First I create a batch:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/batch' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token redacted>' \
--data-raw ''
```

Response: `{"batch_id":"OWU0NzgxYzUtMjkzZS0xMWVkLTg5NDAtYWUyMDAwNjVjZGU0LTZiODk2MDliZA"}`

So now the next thing I want to try is to verify that batch ID:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/user/scheduled_sends/OWU0NzgxYzUtMjkzZS0xMWVkLTg5NDAtYWUyMDAwNjVjZGU0LTZiODk2MDliZA' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token redacted>'
```

The response is, oddly, a `200 OK` with just `[]` which doesn't seem right does it? I created a batch and it has an ID, so why can't I verify its existence?

Documentation here states: https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/cancel-scheduled-sends/validate-batch-id

> When you pass a valid `batch_id` to this endpoint, it will return a `200`
> status code and the batch ID itself.
>
> If you pass an invalid `batch_id` to the endpoint, you will receive a
> 400 level status code and an error message.
>
> A `batch_id` does not need to be assigned to a scheduled send to be
> considered valid. A successful response means only that the batch_id
> has been created, but it does not indicate that it has been associated
> with a send.

Interestingly if I put **any arbitrary string** in that URL instead of a batch ID, I also get a 200 OK with empty array. I cannot even reproduce what the document is saying about receiving a 400 error for an invalid ID.

However if I take it on faith that the batch WAS created, I would go ahead and try to send an email with it:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token redacted>' \
--data-raw '{
    "batch_id": "OWU0NzgxYzUtMjkzZS0xMWVkLTg5NDAtYWUyMDAwNjVjZGU0LTZiODk2MDliZA",
    "send_at": 1661969713,
    "personalizations": [{
        "to": [{
                "email": "thatemail@mycompany.com",
                "name": "John Doe"
            }
        ]
    }],
    "from": {
        "email": "myemail@mycompany.com",
        "name": "Jane Doe"
    },
    "reply_to": {
        "email": "customer_service@example.com",
        "name": "Example Customer Service Team"
    },
    "subject": "Example Email 6",
    "content": [{
            "type": "text/html",
            "value": "<p>Test email!</p><p>%open-track%</p>"
        }
    ],
    "custom_args":{
        "sf-id": "some-arbitrary-id6",
        "sf-org-id": "some-arbitrary-org-id"
    },
    "mail_settings": {
        "sandbox_mode": {
            "enable": false
        }
    },
    "tracking_settings": {
        "click_tracking": {
            "enable": true,
            "enable_text": false
        },
        "open_tracking": {
            "enable": true,
            "substitution_tag": "%open-track%"
        },
        "subscription_tracking": {
            "enable": false
        }
    }
}
'
```

At the time of writing that timestamp is for 3h from now, resolving at 2:15PM August 31st Eastern Time. I send that call and get `202 Accepted`.

Then, finally, I attempt to pause the batch.

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/user/scheduled_sends/OWU0NzgxYzUtMjkzZS0xMWVkLTg5NDAtYWUyMDAwNjVjZGU0LTZiODk2MDliZA' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token redacted>' \
--data-raw '{"status": "pause"}'
```

My response is a `404 NOT FOUND` with:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "field": null,
            "message": "batch id not found"
        }
    ]
}
```

So... what is going on here???

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to do this? Also, batches can only be cancelled up to 10 minutes before the scheduled send time, could that be an issue for you in this testing?

Comment: I am using Postman to test this out, so no code at the moment. I can share JSON samples when I'm back at my work desk. And 10 minutes was not a factor here. I created a batch, scheduled some emails for several hours ahead, and then was unable to cancel them because the call to do so returned `"batch id not found"`. (And sure enough, several hours later the emails sent.)

Comment: @philnash I have edited the question to contain cURL exports of the calls I'm making and responses I'm getting. Would appreciate if I could understand this better so that I can present this feature set to the customer accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a few things:

- It turns out I was missing a step here. The first time I want to put in a pause or cancel on a batch, I actually need to `POST /v3/user/scheduled_sends/` with `batch_id` in the request body. I was trying `PATCH`. Strange behaviour here as the batch ID already exists, but OK.
- After my first successful test of this, the entire behaviour of the `GET /v3/mail/batch/{batch_id}` API changed for me. I am no longer able to reproduce getting back an empty array. Every response is either a success with the batch ID or a fail.

I don't know why these behaviours changed, but they did. There may be some quirk in which fresh accounts that have never paused/cancelled a batch simply do not have a functional "validate batch" call. Now that I have done a successful pause for the first time, the behaviour of `GET /v3/mail/batch/{batch_id}` finally matches the documentation.